# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'No hay ningún reconocedor instalado. '

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer un asistente virtual y hasta ahora esto comenzando y me sale este error System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'No hay ningún reconocedor instalado.' el cual no se como solucionar, inclusive tengo las librerias necesarias ya importadas y no he entendido ese error

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine reconocedor = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();//inicio del reconocimiento de voz
    SpeechSynthesizer asistente = new SpeechSynthesizer();// inicio del asistente
    bool habilitarReconocimiento=false;
    string speech;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iniciDeGramaticas();
    }
     
    void iniciDeGramaticas()
    
       [error] reconocedor.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"comando\comandos.txt")))));//EN ESTA LINEA DE CODIGO ME SALE EL ERROR
        reconocedor.RequestRecognizerUpdate();//actualizador para mic
        reconocedor.SpeechRecognized += Reconocedor_SpeechRecognized;//accion cuando habla el asistente
        asistente.SpeakStarted += Asistente_SpeakStarted;//accion cuando reconoce el comando
        asistente.SpeakCompleted += Asistente_SpeakCompleted;//accion de cuando termina el comando
        reconocedor.AudioLevelUpdated += Reconocedor_AudioLevelUpdated;//obtiene el nivel de entrada del micro
        reconocedor.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();//seleccionar dispositivo por defecto
        reconocedor.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);//
    }
```